# Отображение знаков форматирования eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Здравствуйте. Как убрать отображение форматирование кода в Eclipse?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Скорее всего, нужно выключить whitespace characters. Попробуй Window->Preferences, General->Editors->Text Editors, и там выключи галочку Show whitespace characters